# iterating loops comparing the current index with the next index java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

Here is my code

```java
String endDate;
int currentIndex = 0;
int nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
while(currentIndex < aList.size() - 1)
{
    endDate = aList.get(nextIndex).getStartDate();
    if(endDate == null)
    {
        endDate = episodeEnd.toString();
    }
    aList.get(currentIndex).setEndDate(endDate);
    currentIndex++;
    nextIndex++
}
```

aList looks like this:

```
[itemA, 2019-09-18, 2019-11-13],
[itemB, 2019-11-13, 2019-12-19],
[itemC, 2019-12-19, null]
```

itemC end date will always be null since there is no itemD.

The point of the code is to make the endDate of each item the same as the start date of the next item. If there is no next item then the end date should be the end date of a separate time period defined elsewhere in the code I.E. episodeEnd

The problem I'm having is iterating the list properly.

The loop never reaches the end as I need to set the last index to aList.size() - 1 to prevent indexOutOfRange. Since it never reaches the end, itemC never gets checked therefore, itemC end date remains null.

My other thought was to use nested for loops with the outer loop looking at the currentIndex and the nested loop looking at the

How do I code this so that itemC gets checked and avoid an indexOutOfRange?

Comment: `endDate = episodeEnd.toString();` ... with a _lowercase e_ for `endDate` ?

Comment: sorry... typo :-). I've edited the code

Comment: If the start date is always set, then why do you need to modify `itemC`? If it's `endDate` is supposed to stay `null`, then this code already works.

Comment: the end date isn't supposed to stay null. the end date is supposed to be the start date of the next item or in the case of itemC the end date of a different time period

Comment: The easiest way would be to set the itemC end date on the next statement outside the loop something like aList.get(nextIndex).setEndDate(endDate). If you want to do it inside the loop then introduce a if statement to check the value of currentIndex == aList.size() and set it inside there and let everything else run in else clause of this if statement.

Comment: @Aayush Thank you. This is the answer I was looking for but I can't mark it as correct as it's a comment but +1 to you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `currentIndex` will be equal to `aList.size() - 1` thus referencing the last element in the list, so you can set its `endDate` just after the loop:

```
while (currentIndex < aList.size() - 1) {
// ...
}
aList.get(currentIndex).setEndDate(episodeEnd.toString());
```